# Rails: Get urls from database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, feedzirra

Trying to get into Rails and feedzirra! :) I have stores multiple feed urls into database and have problems to fetch those and get it work feedzirra.
Urls needs to be like this:

```
feed_urls = ["http://www.feedurl1.com/feed", "http://www.feedurl2.com/feed"]
```

This is what I got now but it is not working? Why?

```
  def self.get_feeds
     feed_urls = Feedurls.find(:all, :select => "url")
     update_from_feeds(feed_urls)
  end
```

Console puts me this:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :037 > FeedEntry.get_feeds
Feedurls Load (0.6ms)  SELECT url FROM `feedurls` 
TypeError: can't convert nil into String
```

Thanks for all help! :)

Comment: Provide your `schema` information, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just simply use:

```
feed_urls = Feedurls.all.map(&:url)
```

If your feedurls is simple table (and it should be), then the code above will work nice.

Comment: Just got undefined method `map' ??

Comment: Okey! That was it!! :) Thank you very much!